# Gmail says the username is 'already in use' and 'not in use' at the same time

Tags: gmail, google-account

I'm helping my father today to update his Google account. Below is a step-by-step procedure of what we did, and where we got in trouble.

### 1.  The procedure step-by-step

First we logged in with his usual emailaddress `karel.mulier@hotmail.com`. We got into his Google account, and pressed on the icon representing the Gmail:

[image]

Google immediately showed us a message, encouraging us to add a Gmail to this Google-account. I've taken a screenshot, and added translations from Dutch to English in green ink:

[image]

As you can see, the username `karelmulier` is already in use! This is very worrying to us, because my father never created a gmail address. We fear that someone with bad intentions created this account on my fathers name.

I search for account recovery on Google, and got onto this link:

https://accounts.google.com/signin/recovery

I get a form where I can fill in the 'lost' account that I want to recover. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

As you can see, Google claims that the account `karelmulier@gmail.com` doesn't exist.

### 2.  Our confusion

When I attempt to add the Gmail address `karelmulier@gmail.com` to my fathers existing account, Google refuses because it "is already in use". When I try to recover it (from some bad guy abusing my fathers name), Google tells me it doesn't exist.
How is this possible?

Comment: It’s possible someone used that gmail address before and deleted their account. This would prevent the username from being reused.

Comment: And it’s likely no one is abusing your father’s name. It’s more likely that someone with the same name created that email address a long time ago.

Answer (score 3):

## Short answer

Choose another username

## Explanation

While Gmail is free, it's a service from a private company. If they set algorithms that deny an email address there isn't anything that we could do to convince them to give you that email address.

Bear in mind that Google doesn't require that usernames match the name of the email address requester.

From https://support.google.com/mail/answer/56256?hl=en

> **The username I want is taken**
>
> You won't be able to get a certain Gmail address if the username you
>   requested is:
>
> - Already being used
> - Very similar to an existing username (for example, if example@gmail.com already exists, you can't use examp1e@gmail.com)
> - The same as a username that someone used in the past and then deleted
> - Reserved by Google to prevent spam or abuse

## Related

### Web Applications

- [If I close my Gmail account will somebody be able to register my previous mail address?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/90014/88163)
- [How to retire a Gmail address without it becoming available to others?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/79685/88163)

### Official Gmail Product Forum

- [Claiming a deleted username](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/AiFF8ie0_DA)
- [I want an Email name that doesn't exist but Google says isn't available](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/cBnJ8lx81fk)

Comment: Thank you @Rubén. Is there absolutely no way to reach google and get the email, perhaps by giving proof, like my fathers identity card?

Comment: @K.Mulier AFAIK there isn't. I added some references to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to a number of links returned by "periods in gmail email address," [Gmail ignores periods in an email address](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7436150?hl=en). The two email addresses listed in the question are considered identical, which explains the "already in use" explanation.

Dots don't matter in Gmail addresses: (from Gmail support page)

If someone accidentally adds dots to your address when emailing you, you'll still get that email. For example, if your email is johnsmith@gmail.com, you own all dotted versions of your address:

```
john.smith@gmail.com
jo.hn.sm.ith@gmail.com
j.o.h.n.s.m.i.t.h@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

GMail doesn't let you pick a username which was in use in the past, but was deleted. It is quite possible that the original owner of the account deleted their account, meaning that the account doesn't exists but the name can not be reclaimed.